# Convert Function from SQL Server to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-functions

Can someone convert this function from SQL Server to PostgreSQL?

This function takes the start and end dates and create the date range and produces the output.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DateRange]
(     
      @Increment              CHAR(1),
      @StartDate              DATETIME,
      @EndDate                DATETIME
)
RETURNS  
@SelectedRange    TABLE 
(IndividualDate DATETIME)
AS 
BEGIN
      ;WITH cteRange (DateRange) AS (
            SELECT @StartDate
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 
                  CASE
                        WHEN @Increment = 'd' THEN DATEADD(dd, 1, DateRange)
                        WHEN @Increment = 'w' THEN DATEADD(ww, 1, DateRange)
                        WHEN @Increment = 'm' THEN DATEADD(mm, 1, DateRange)
                  END
            FROM cteRange
            WHERE DateRange <= 
                  CASE
                        WHEN @Increment = 'd' THEN DATEADD(dd, -1, @EndDate)
                        WHEN @Increment = 'w' THEN DATEADD(ww, -1, @EndDate)
                        WHEN @Increment = 'm' THEN DATEADD(mm, -1, @EndDate)
                  END)

      INSERT INTO @SelectedRange (IndividualDate)
      SELECT DateRange
      FROM cteRange
      OPTION (MAXRECURSION 3660);
      RETURN
END
GO
```

Comment: This site is for programming questions. It is not a code translation service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to write your own function, this is already built in:

```
select * 
from generate_series(date '2016-01-01', date '2016-09-01', interval '2' day);
```

Details in the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html

Comment: Thanks a lot a_horse_with_no_name. This functions works great!